# How to provide type hints in JavaScript using JSDoc for Apollo Client based code?

Tags: javascript, apollo-client, jsdoc

I have trouble setting up type hints for my JavaScript code using JSDoc (trying to make this work with VSCode and WebStorm).

As first step, I converted GraphQL schema into set of JSDoc `@typedef` entries using `@graphql-codegen/cli`. For the sake of this conversation, lets talk about this one:

```js
// schema.js

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Country
 * @property {string} code
 * @property {string} name
 */
```

Then, somewhere in my `App.js` I tried writing:

```js
// App.js

const GET_COUNTRIES = gql`
  query GetCountries {
    countries {
      code
      name
    }
  }
`;

/**
 * @typedef {import("./schema").Country} Country
 * @typedef {import("@apollo/client").QueryResult} QueryResult

 * @returns {QueryResult<Country>}
 */
const useGetCountries = () => {
  return useQuery(GET_COUNTRIES);
};
```

However, it looks like the type definitions from `schema.js` are being ignored (both `App.js` and `schema.js` are in the same directory).

My question is this: is it possible to setup something like this - have IDE pickup JSDoc type definitions and provide type hints? If the answer is YES, how would I go around settings this up?

I've created a simple repro on CodeSandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/graphql-type-hints-n1vh0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was unable to make this work using just JSDoc, I had a good success using the same `@graphql-codegen/cli` utility and generating `.d.ts` file instead. After that, I was able to provide correct type hints using the following code:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import("../types/schema").Country} Country
 * @typedef {import("../types/helpers").ApolloQueryResult<{countries: Country[]}>} QueryResult
 *
 * @returns {QueryResult}
 */
const useGetCountries = () => {
  return useQuery(GET_COUNTRIES);
};
```

I also implemented `helpers.d.ts` so that I can easily make fields of my choosing optional (unlike the built-int `Partial` type that makes all fiels optional) and make `data` filed of QueryResult optional as well (as in Apollo documentation. Didn't had the time to figure out why it is not already in Apollo's `.d.ts`)

```js
type OptionalKey<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>;

export type ApolloQueryResult<TData = any, TVariables = any> = OptionalKey<
  QueryResult<TData, TVariables>,
  "data"
>;
```